# How to properly use onError+Throwable in RxJava on Android?

Tags: android, rx-java2

The ObservableEmitter's onError needs a Throwable instance to be passed in, but what is the best practice if I just have some error data? Like below:

```
    Observable<JSONObject> o1 = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<JSONObject> e) throws Exception {
    RemoteApi.getInstance().addR(context, tag, new AsyncCallback<JSONObject, Error>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
        if(e.isDisposed()) {
            return;
        }
        e.onNext(result);
         e.onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Error error) {
        if(e.isDisposed()) {
            return;
        }
        e.onError(new Throwable(error.getCode() + " " + error.getMessage()));
        }
    });
    }
});
```

How to pass the error data properly out? I just create a wrapper class for this kind of exception:

```
    private static class RxJavaExceptionError extends Exception {
    private Object object;
    public RxJavaExceptionError(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
    public Object get() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

I use the object member to pass data. But I found out I need to many use instanceof to determine if it's RxJavaExceptionError, which is not very delightful. So what the best practice in this case? I don't think this is an unusual case.

Did I express it clearly? My English is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont quite understand your use case. In case you want the throwable of the error and propagate through the pipeline, did you try the operator onErrorResumeNext?

```
/**
 * Here we can see how onErrorResumeNext works and emit an item in case that an error occur in the pipeline and an exception is propagated
 */
@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeNext() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(null)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                            .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) :
                                    Observable.just(null).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                    Schedulers.newThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                return Observable.just("I save the world for extinction!");
            })
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

If you want to see more example take a look here

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java